# Insert ASCII in variable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ascii

I'm trying to insert this ascii img:

````
                              :hNMMh.             
                             .sosooNm`            
                             +sosysyds            
                             s+o/oossy:           
              `.`  -+shho++soy+oo+osyoy:::...`    
     `o:`  `+yhhhoyhhyds/-:-os++oshhsos+/+////+/: 
      oyo//yyyyyyyyhhyhyyssoyymmNmyo///+oosyyyhhd-
      /+shhhhhddhdmhyyyyyyyyyyyyyyysyhhhyyyyyyyyho
     :o+//////+osddyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyhdhyyyyyyyyd
    `:`          -mhyyyyyyyyyyyyyyhhdmdddhyyyyyyhN
                 ydyyyyyyyyhhhhddmmmdmmddhhyyyyhdm
                 :dhyhyysyhyyyyhhyyhddmdhysyyhyhyd
    .-:-`         :dhyyyyyyhyyyhyyyyyssdhysyyddyyy
  .//::///-`       :dyyyyyyyyyd+://::+:+hdhhhdhyh/
 :/----:::///-.`    +hy+yyysssh::+::/+/sdhyyyyyyh`
-/---------::////:-.-h+://+///y+/+soooddhyyhhyyh- 
o-----------------://dy+:-:+syyd/+hso+hhhhhhyso-  
+::///:::::::::--::::sdhyshhyyyyh:/ssso/s++y`     
       ```.o/://://///mhyhddhyyyhs--//://-+:      
           `o--:::::::ydyyymdhyyyd:-:://--o       
            /:--------:dyyhsydhyyhs-:/:--+`       
             +:-------:syyd:-odhyyd/:--:+`        
        `.    :/:--:/::-dhhhyo+dhyhs:-//`         
         ++:.`  ....:/--odyyym::mhyhhys           
          ///:::::::++///d//sh--ydyyyyh+          
           -+---------:::+s-:s-:+hhyhy/y          
            `//--------:::h:+o:-  :sos-y          
              .:/-----:/+sy/s-      /o-o:         
                 ------++/-:++       .s/s`        
                    /yyo+/:-          `y:o/       
                     ``                -s-:o-     
                                        s:-:+o.   
                                        .so++//
````

In a variable to log it in the terminal, but I can't close the " or '. any idea?

Comment: tried template strings \` \` ?

Comment: "I'm trying to insert this ascii img" — What have you tried? Show us a [mcve]. Tell us what error messages you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, but in my opinion the best one is to store this text in a file (`image.txt` for example), and read it with the `fs` module like this

```
var image = fs.readfilesync('image.txt');
console.log(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all use literals `` or readFile for keeping new lines and spaces.
2. Make sure that your terminal use monotype font, because you need the same width for every character.